# Connect to Cloud DB

Tags: sql-server, cloud

I have an SQL database in a data center in the cloud and I need to create a linked server, to transfer data from that database to a database at my premises.

Could you tell me how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you mean SQL Server.

```
-- link
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'HOST_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO  
-- setup login credentials
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
    @rmtsrvname = N'HOST_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME',   
    @locallogin = NULL ,   
    @useself = N'True' ;  
GO
```

then you can query remote server

```
-- insert into new local table all data from remote server table 'databases'
SELECT * INTO new_local_table FROM [HOST_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME].master.sys.databases;  
GO
```

see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff772782.aspx for more details

Comment: Fisrst of all thanks for the quick answer , it appears that i was executing the right query but i was given the wrong credentials :) ;) .